# How to keep jQuery plugin after an ASP callback?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-plugins

I'm using the [tipsy](https://github.com/jaz303/tipsy) jQuery plugin on an ASP page.
I activate it at page load in my master page:

```
if (jQuery.fn.tipsy) {
    $('.north').tipsy({ gravity: 'n', fade: true });
    $('.south').tipsy({ gravity: 's', fade: true });
    $('.east').tipsy({ gravity: 'e', fade: true });
    $('.west').tipsy({ gravity: 'w', fade: true });
}
```

The problem appears when I make a callback, elements that where targeted by the plugin are refreshed and aren't registered anymore.

Is there a way to keep the plugin active on these elements after a callback or should I re-initialize it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to re-initialize the plugin. Inside `Page_Load` trigger a client event on postback:

```
if (Page.IsPostBack) {
    RadScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "postback", "$.event.trigger({type:'postback.event'})", true);
}
```

An in js:

```
$(document).on('postback.event', () => {
   // Init plugin
});
```

Comment: As it's partial and my ScriptManager is not in the callback panel, the script doesn't seem to be registered and the trigger not fired.